# Efficient concatenation

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, concatenation, bitwise-operators

I am trying to send a message over an LPWAN and one of the issues I am facing is trying to get my message as short as possible.

For example:

I have two integers (0-100) and two Booleans which I have to convert to a Hex to send over the LPWAN. Example:

- 24
- 63
- True
- False

When I concatenate this as 246310 (Hex:3C226), this will take 3 bytes. However, I know that my first integer will never be higher than 50, which is just 6 bits. Is it possible for me to make the hex message shorter than 3C226?

Comment: @LPs They are always 2 integers and 2 booleans, the first integer is always 0 to 50 and the second integer always 0 to 100

Comment: In your comment you specify that the second integer is in the range [0, 100], but in your question it's [0, 80]. Please edit your question if it's actually [0, 100].

Comment: Furthermore, unless there are any dependencies between these variables, you will always need at least `ceil(log(51 * 101 * 2 * 2) / log(2)) = 15` bits to send these messages. unwind's answer is as efficient as possible in this case, and it's also quite easy to work with.

Comment: done, eventhough it doesnt make a difference for the question, seeing as 100 is 7 bits as is 80

Comment: It almost made a difference. If you have the ranges [0, 50], [0, 79], [0, 1], [0, 1], you only need at least 14 bits if you use another technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that should be possible.

The number of bits for your fields are:

- `integer0`: Integer 0..50, 6 bits.
- `integer1`: Integer 0..80, 7 bits.
- `flag0`: Boolean, 1 bit.
- `flag1`: Boolean, 1 bit.

So that's a total of 6 + 7 + 1 + 1 = 15 bits.

Here's how to encode:

```
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|15|14|13|12|11|10| 9| 8| 7| 6| 5| 4| 3| 2| 1| 0|
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |                 |                    |  |  |
|  |  integer0       |  integer1          |f0|f1|
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+

uint16_t encode(uint8_t integer0, uint8_t integer1, bool flag0, bool flag1)
{
  return ((uint16_t) integer0 << 9) | ((uint16_t) integer1 << 2) | ((uint16_t) flag0 << 1) | flag1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using 2 bytes, the value can be stored as:

```
   FirstNum         Second        1st bool     2nd bool
<------------> <------------> <------------> <------------>
     6bits          7bits          1bit          1bit
```

Still you are left with 1 bit.

Use `left shift` << operation to achieve the above.